# How many $4$ digit numbers with distinct digits can be formed using $0,1,2,3,4,5$?

Tags: permutations, combinations

So left most digit can be filled with $5$ (can't use $0$ there) then next one got $5$ option then $4$ and $3$. So the answer is $5\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 =300$. Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: So if repeating is allowed answer would be 5.6.6.6 = 1080 ?

Comment: Yes, that would be the ans.

Answer (score 2):

Community wiki answer so that the question can be marked answered:

As stated in the comments, your calculation is correct.